# android: how to access ressources in the res/raw directory via BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, loading, bufferedreader

i save some ressources in the res/raw directory which i then would like to read with my custom loader.

how can i do this?

ideally i would get a BufferedReader on them.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the common way :

```
InputStream rawRes = getResources().openRawResource(yourResourceName);
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(rawRes);
//no need of a buffer, it already has an [internal one][1].
```

You can also put it in the assets folder and access it like that :

```
InputStream rawRes = context.getAssets().open("fileName.extension");
Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rawRes, "UTF8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`getResources().openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream`. `InputStreamReader` to get a reader. `InputStreamReader` has built-in buffering.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i just figured it out:

```
InputStream is = app.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ship);
ship = OBJ.load(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)));
```